# Java how to wait for a dialog window

Tags: java, user-interface

I am working on a Java GUI program right now. (Using Eclipse+Windowbuilder)

I have the following situation:

The subprogram B calls a Dialog Window to ask the user for input and terminates with calling program A.
But I do not want program A to be called yet. It should be called after the Dialog Window terminated.

```
B:
dialogWindow();
<------- here B should wait for dialogWindow to finish
A();
exit();
```

Is there a **way to wait** for dialogWindow()? (I do not want to move the A(); command)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The dialogWindow is actually just a normal JFrame.

Comment: set the Modal flag to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `setModal(true)` for `YourPopUpComponent` that should inherit from `JDialog` or use `JOptionPane.showDialog`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "A", "B", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);        
    if (resp == 0)
     System.out.println("call methodA()");
    else
        System.out.println("call foo()");


    }
}
```

Comment: To further demonstrate this, you could use `int response = JOptionPane...` and then show that the System.out.println can print the selected response value.

Comment: I really like that method. That solves the question.

Answer (score -2):

GUI programming in Java is event based.

Thus you add an ActionListener to the submit button of your dialog window, this ActionListener will call A() and terminates.

Comment: He said he doesnt want to move the call to A(). Setting the modal flag on the dialog is the solution he requires.